# Dependencies not being built from command line execution with Code::Blocks

Tags: c, windows, static-libraries, codeblocks

This is all within a Windows environment.

I have a main project that depends on 2 libraries (e.g. lib.a). When I rebuild through the Code::Blocks IDE, it cleans both library projects and the main project as expected. It then builds all 3 projects, libraries first, as expected with no issues.

I try to do the same thing from the command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\STW\CodeBlocks\codeblocks.exe" src\emb\bwk\vehicle_monitor\pjt\vehicle_monitor.cbp --target="Release" --rebuild
```

But it doesn't clean or build the library projects like it does in the IDE, and therefore produces errors:

```
tricore-g++.exe: error: ..\..\..\..\ext\micro_cdr\result\libmicro_cdr.a: No such file or directory
tricore-g++.exe: error: ..\..\..\..\ext\micro_dds\result\libmicro_dds.a: No such file or directory
Process terminated with status 1 (1 minute(s), 6 second(s))
2 error(s), 39 warning(s) (1 minute(s), 6 second(s))
```

I tried all command line options and I don't see any log files being produced

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\STW\CodeBlocks\codeblocks.exe" "Z:\workspace\autoyard\src\emb\bwk\vehicle_monitor\pjt\vehicle_monitor.cbp" --target="Release" --rebuild --log-to-file --debug-log-to-file /d --verbose
```

Is there something I'm missing on the command line?

Command line options from using `--help` option:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps adding `--debug-log` will give you more info about what codeblocks is doing.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I can see the debug log if I launch the IDE, but it doesn't show me anything, or where it's saved (if at all) if I just do a build from the command line.

Comment: Odd. That option should do that if added to the command line. Add `--verbose` too. Any change?

Comment: Tried that too and nothing different. The only log I get is the build log in html format because I selected that option in the gui as a setting before closing and running from command line.

Comment: So, it doesn't you an error for those options but just ignores them? Very odd. Try `--foo` do you get an error?

Comment: `--foo` gives an error as unknown option.  Maybe those options are doing something, but I have no idea where they are saving the files if they are. The only one I see produced is the html build log.

Comment: The output should come to stdout. It's strange that you seem to have options that are not listed in their wiki page. Perhaps you can run with just the `--help` option and put the output in the question. That way it's easier to see what options we have to play with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255280/discussion-between-ls6777-and-ted-lyngmo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 answers/conclusions that I was able to come to:

1. Build the workspace on the command line

   - `"C:\Program Files (x86)\STW\CodeBlocks\codeblocks.exe" "C:\Users\Ryan Gleim\Desktop\CB_workspace.workspace" --target="Release" --rebuild`
   - This will build the entire workspace and will build the dependencies in the correct order
   - This won't work for my build system though because we don't have workspaces on the build system
2. Build each project, in the order required, individually

   - `"C:\Program Files (x86)\STW\CodeBlocks\codeblocks.exe" "Z:\workspace\autoyard\src\ext\micro_cdr\pjt\micro_cdr.cbp" --target="Release" --rebuild`
   - `"C:\Program Files (x86)\STW\CodeBlocks\codeblocks.exe" "Z:\workspace\autoyard\src\ext\micro_dds\pjt\micro_dds.cbp" --target="Release" --rebuild`
   - `"C:\Program Files (x86)\STW\CodeBlocks\codeblocks.exe" "Z:\workspace\autoyard\src\emb\bwk\vehicle_monitor\pjt\vehicle_monitor.cbp" --target="Release" --rebuild`
   - This allows the user to control order of builds for dependencies
   - Requires multiple command line commands, but works for a build system that doesn't have a workspace